# Patching media query css for IE8 as part of a build process

Tags: internet-explorer-8, media-queries

Bootstrap 3 uses [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to dynamically parse and patch media queries in the css right in the client.

This isn't an ideal solution for IE8 which is already **slow**.

Does there exist an external build script that can generate the version of the css that would otherwise be build on the client?

---

The build would convert media queries to a bunch of classes and there will still need to be a js file that will change the media query classes on the DOM elements based on browser width

Comment: If you don't want IE8 to use media queries, then just remove respond.js from your site, and setup your CSS to have sensible defaults outside of the media queries, so that browsers without media query support will use those defaults. No need to have a separate CSS file or anything like that; just use CSS's normal fall-back defaulting.

Comment: ie8 doesnt support media queries, but we would like to use them.